# Show that the integral $\int(xu - 3tu^2) dx$ is invariant for the $KdV$ equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a problem solving the problem about showing the integral is invariant for the KdV equation. 
The problem is as following:

Show that integral of $\int(xu - 3tu^2) dx$ is invariant for the $KdV$ equation.

Can anyone help? I'm kind of stuck here...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Try defining $F(t)=\int(xu - 3tu^2) dx$ and try to show that $F'(t)=0$. (You will need to insert the KdV and do some integration by parts.)